# Trouble removing duplicates in a list

Tags: java, algorithm, list, duplicates

I've been working with list of objects having a date (actually strings) and an ID lately. Dates are stored this way with a string : "yyyy-mm-dd".
So I've got a very long list (about 80 000 elements) looking like this :

```
[{id:"15655454", date:"2014-11-15"}, {id:"15655454", date:"2014-11-15"}, {id:"15655454", date:"2014-11-15"}, {id:"15655454", date:"2014-10-17"}, {id:"15655454", date:"2014-10-17"}, {id:"15655454", date:"2014-10-17"}, {id:"15655454", date:"2014-10-17"}, {id:"15655454", date:"2014-10-17"}, {id:"15655455", date:"2014-09-23"}, ...]
```

It's actually a java class, a bit more complicated, but the global idea is here. (it does have more than just two fields actualy, but it's not important here I think)

As you can see, it's sorted by ID.

What I want to do is :
- if there are several dates for one single ID : keep only the newest date.
- if there are several equal newest dates for one single ID : keep them all.

So here's what I've tried so far :

```
List<Element> results = new ArrayList<Element>();
results.initiateList();

int count = 0;

while(count < results.size()-1) {
    if (results.get(count).getID().equals(results.get(count+1).getID())) {
            String[] dateI = results.get(count).getDate().split("-");
            String[] dateJ = results.get(count+1).getDate().split("-");
            int yearI = Integer.parseInt(dateI[0]);
            int yearJ = Integer.parseInt(dateJ[0]);
            int monthI = Integer.parseInt(dateI[1]);
            int monthJ = Integer.parseInt(dateJ[1]);
            int dayI = Integer.parseInt(dateI[2]);
            int dayJ = Integer.parseInt(dateJ[2]);

            if (results.get(count).getDate()== null) {
                results.remove(count);
                if (count != 0) {
                    count--;
                }
            } else if (results.get(count+1).getDate()== null) {
                results.remove(count+1);
            } else if ( yearI > yearJ ) {
                results.remove(count+1);
            } else if ( yearI < yearJ ) {
                results.remove(count);
                if (count != 0) {
                    count--;
                }
            } else if ( yearI == yearJ && monthI > monthJ ) {
                results.remove(count+1);
            } else if ( yearI == yearJ && monthI < monthJ ) {
                results.remove(count);
                if (count != 0) {
                    count--;
                }
            } else if ( yearI == yearJ && monthI == monthJ && dayI > dayJ ) {
                results.remove(count+1);
            } else if ( yearI == yearJ && monthI == monthJ && monthI < monthJ ) {
                results.remove(count);
                if (count != 0) {
                    count--;
                }
            } else if ( yearI == yearJ && monthI == monthJ && dayI == dayJ ) {
                count++;
            }
        } else {
            count++;
        }


    }
```

But this doesn't work, and I don't understand why. I feel like I've considered all the possible cases, but still, it doesn't remove all duplicates. The problem is that I still have some duplicate, for example, the list will still contains several different dates for one single ID.

Methods initiateList(), getDate() and getID() are properly implemented since I use them at a lot of other different places, and they work fine there.
InitiateList() put all the elements in the list, if I try to display them on console it works properly.

I don't see what's wrong with the while loop, but I guess I missed something (and it's probably pretty basic ...)

Comment: Try a debugger. And look at it step by step. Create a small example where your code fails (and add it to your question).

Comment: is you are able to use a Collection, why dont implement equals, compareTo ans use Collections methods???

Comment: Consider using `Map` to store your `id`-`date` pair. If `id` exists, then check if `date` is latest - yes, store it, otherwise ignore. Also, parse your date to something like `LocalDate` to make life easier for you.

Comment: IOC: **Implementation Of Concept.**
First try to implement the logic on a small use case, verify that logic and then only move to the real use-case.

Comment: @kazu First of all, you should parse your list in **decreasing order**. This way, you can remove an element without problem, as your index will go on the next element anyway. Then, you can put your comparison function in a separate function, that'll be more clear.

Comment: Provide us with working code that reproduces the problem. This is pseudocode as can be seen right of the bat by this line: `results.initiateList();` There are several more issues, for example: you do a `==null` check where it would already have thrown a NPE if it was null.

Comment: Sort by id then date (meaning, if ids are equal, compare dates). Then parse your list and keep every first new id you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think trying compare to neighbor elements is wrong because it is not necessary the case that both of them with the same id.Maybe you should try a different approach by using groupBy in collectors something like this

```
 public List<Element> removeDuplicates(List<Element> theList) {
    // Getting a map where key is an id of element and the list is all the elements with the same id
    Map<String, List<Element>> theData = theList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(elem -> elem.getId()));

    List<Element> result = new ArrayList<>();
    //Now we go over the map and from each list we take the element with newes date
    theData.forEach((id, elementsList) -> {
        Element elementWithNewstDate = getNewest(elementsList);
        result.add(elementWithNewstDate);
    });

    return result;
}

private Element getNewest(List<Element> elementsList) {
    // Sorting by newest date
    elementsList.sort(Comparator.comparing(element -> getDateFromElement(element)));
    //Taking the first one becouse it supose to be the newst if i am wrong take the last element
    return elementsList.get(0);
}

private Date getDateFromElement(Element element) {
    Date result = null;
    try {
        result = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(element.getDate());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notice it's not 100% correct but it should help as an example

Comment: your first phrase is wrong - the list is sorted by ID

Comment: Well thanks. It works fine now. I had to modify a bit getNewest() so it can return a list (since I can have several dates equal to the newest, and in this case I keep them all) but that was easy from your work. I'm not good with Comparators, and this is a fine example of how to use it.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing unwanted comparisions. You can just convert the string to date using the below snippet.

```
    String sDate1="2014-11-15";  
    Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sDate1);
    System.out.println("Date : "+date1);
    System.out.println("Date value :"+date1.getTime());
```

The you can compare the output of corresponding dates getTime() to decide higher/lower dates. You can reduce your code and debug then.

Comment: actually the strings can be compared directly if formatted as 'yyyy-MM-dd'